# CSS media query change not working in shinydashboard

Tags: css, media-queries, shiny

I'm having a problem with a media query change in my custom.css file using the R [shinydashboard](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/). I'm trying to adjust the width of the side panel and then make all the subsequent appropriate changes. An example webapp can be seen [here](https://winston.shinyapps.io/dash/#). The starting point is and involves four CSS changes to my custom sytlesheet:

```
<body...>
  <header...>   
  <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
    <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
```

#### Step 1

When the width of the browser is 768px or greater I increase the width of the sidebar from 220px to 240px (works):

```
.left-side {
    width: 240px;
}
```

#### Step 2

Because the sidebar is now protrudes 20px when collapsed, I change the media query from 220px to 240px as well (wont't change to 220px):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.left-side.collapse-left {
    left: -240px;
}
```

#### Step 3

Sidebar now needs to be shifted left so right edge of sidebar is not sticking out for browser width of 768px or less (wont't change to 220px):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -240px;
}
```

#### Step 4

Last change shifts sidebar right so it is not off left side of screen when collapsed (wont't change to 220px):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 240px;
}
```

#### Other Notes

I can change it without the media query, but then the media query does not activate for different browser widths:

```
.left-side.collapse-left {
    left: -240px;
}
```

It seems that I can make the changes in AdminLTE.min.css to @media, but obviously not the approach I want to take.

Comment: Is this `min-width: 768px` what you wanted or did you want `max-width` ?

Comment: @Huangism. It's the min-width: 768px that makes the appropriate initial change when I ""Inspect" the website and make the change. It appears some will involve max width as well, such as .row-offcanvas-left.active. Though, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the media query stuff, so I could be way off in what I'm doing. I know for sure I want to adjust that .left-side width from 220px to 240px and then make subsequent changes, but can't seem to get any media queries to stick.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add info on when you wanted to do css change. As in when the screen goes smaller or bigger